# Is there any way to select only image and PDF from gallery or file manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf

In my app I am trying to select the only image and PDF file from the gallery or file manager.

But when I am getting all the images and files which is stored in the file manager and gallery.

Here is my code:

```
if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Gallery"]) { 
    UIImagePickerController *pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    pickerView.allowsEditing = YES; pickerView.delegate = self; 
    [pickerView setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAl‌​bum]; 
    [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: show ur tried code

Comment: if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Gallery"])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        pickerView.allowsEditing = YES;
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        [pickerView setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }

Comment: can you elobrate I am getting all the images and files which is stored in the file manager and gallery....?

Comment: i want only the images and pdf files  from the gallery or file manager

Comment: check my answer

Comment: ok i have added the code Karthick, But Now the issue is https://github.com/rao471/select-image-and-pdf-file/projects                                          when i upload the image it is taking for 1st session only , can u solve  @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: then your question is not clear, where u struck , I m not understand excatly what u need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125500/discussion-between-purushothaman-and-anbu-karthik).